# Proxy server forwarding traffic over two consecutive proxies

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, proxy-server

I have a server behind a bastion server and use an SSH tunnel to forward traffic between my laptop and a lab environment.

Using `proxychains-ng` I can successfully forward traffic from commands with this config

```
socks5 localhost 3333
http localhost 2222
```

I am looking to setup a forwarding server, such as squid, to perform this proxy chaining. The intent is to allow any host within the environment to assign this server as a proxy and have their traffic automatically forwarded.

Is there any way to do this with stable, widely used tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easiest to *remove the need* for chaining, by removing the SOCKS part and using a direct SSH tunnel. That is, instead of `ssh -D 1111` specify `ssh -L \*:2222:localhost:2222`. Now any machine on the client side can use `HTTP_PROXY=the_ssh_client:2222` and talk to the second layer of proxy.

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the root problem rather than answering the asked question. I ended up using `ssh -R 3333:localhost:2222` which tested with curl worked well!